# privacy on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an app that lets users post and share files, and currently it's my server that serves these files, but as data grows, so I'm investigating using Amazon S3.  However, I use dynamic rules for what is public and what is private between certain users etc, so the server is the only possible arbiter, i.e. permissions cannot be decided on the app/client end.

Simplistically, I guess I can let my server GET data from S3, then send them back to the app.  But obviously then I'm paying for bandwidth twice not to mention making my server do unnecessary work.

This seems like a fairly common problem, so I wonder how do people typically solve this problem?  (Like I read that Dropbox stores its data on S3.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an application with pretty much the same requirements, and there's a really good solution available. S3 supports signed, expiring S3 URLs to access objects. If you have a private S3 object that you, but not others, can access, you can create such a URL. If you give that URL to someone else, he or she can use it to fetch the object that they normally have no access to.

So the solution for your use case is:

1. User does a GET to the URL on your web site
2. Your code verifies that the user should be able to see the object (via your application's custom, dynamic rules)
3. The web site returns a redirect response to a signed S3 URL that expires soon, say in 5 minutes
4. The user's web browser does a GET to that signed S3 URL. Since it's properly signed and hasn't yet expired, S3 returns the contents of the object directly to the user's browser.

The data goes from S3 to the user without ever traveling back out through your web site. Only users your application has authorized can get the data. And if a user bookmarks or shares the URL it won't work once the expiration time has passed.

Comment: Thank you.  This redirect is a good way to deal with things.  If I want some resources to be essentially permanent for other users, I have the option to set the expiration to 10 years or something, right?

Comment: Yes, you can make the expiration very far in the future.